# String methods cutting out string parts

Tags: c#, string, output

I've built a string builder to add spaces into text if it is capital. The sentence entered would look like this : "ThisIsASentence." Since it starts with a capital, the string builder would modify the sentence to look like this: " This Is A Sentence."

My problem is, If I were to have a sentence like "thisIsASentence." the string builder will separate the sentence like normal : " this Is A Sentence."

Still both have a space in front of the first character.

When the sentence runs through this line:

```
result = result.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + result.Substring(2).ToLower();
```

If the first letter entered was lowercase, it gets cut off and the second letter becomes uppercase.

The line was meant to keep the first letter entered capitalized and set the rest lowercase.

Adding a trim statement before running that line changes nothing with the output.

Here is my overall code right now:

```
        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        // New string named sentence, assigning the text input to sentence.
        string sentence;
        sentence = txtSentence.Text;

        // String builder to let us modify string
        StringBuilder sentenceSB = new StringBuilder();

        /*
         *  For every character in the string "sentence" if the character is uppercase,
         *  add a space before the letter,
         *  if it isn't, add nothing.
         */
        foreach (char c in sentence)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
            {
                sentenceSB.Append(" ");
            }
            sentenceSB.Append(c);
        }


        // Store the edited sentence into the "result" string
        string result = sentenceSB.ToString();

        // Starting at the 2nd spot and going 1, makes the first character capitalized
        // Starting at position 3 and going to end change them to lower case.
        result = result.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + result.Substring(2).ToLower();

        // set the label text to equal "result" and set it visible.
        lblChanged.Text = result.ToString();
        lblChanged.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the code with "thisIsASentence", After your foreach loop, result will be "this Is A Sentence", since it will not insert a space at the beginning.

Then your next line, will take the Character at index 1 (which is the 'h' in this), Make it uppercase, and then append the rest of the string, resulting in "His Is A Sentence"

To fix this, you can do `result = result.Trim()` after the loop, and then start at index 0, making the next line `result = result.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + result.Substring(1).ToLower();`

Comment: Now my issue is that, if the first letter is entered capital. It will change it to lowercase. Could it be that using toUpper(); on an already upper case letter changes it to lower?

Comment: I tested this and it worked fine.  Make sure you are Trimming the result, with result = result.Trim();  or initialize result with: string result = sentenceSB.ToString().Trim();

Answer (score 0):

With `result.SubString(1,1)`, you are assuming the first letter of the input is always capitalized, so your will always add a space in the beginning of the string. You have already seen that this isn't the case.

So I see basically two  options for you:

Wrap that line in an if block that checks for spaces before replacing;

Capitalize the first letter of your input, if it's allowed by your spec.